# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined. Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

Hi I'm trying to submit a form that only have one field using Angular 7 but I'm getting this error on the Input line:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined

My HTML looks like this:

```
    <form #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit(form)">
    <input type="hidden" name="Id" [value]="service.formData.Id">
    <div class="form-group" >
        <div class="input-group" *ngIf="service">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text bg.white">
                        <i class="fas fa-user" [class.green-icon]="Name.valid" [class.red-icon]="Name.invalid && Name.touched"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input name="Name" #Name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Student Name" required maxlength="50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-database"></i> Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have a component that looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentDetailService } from 'src/app/shared/student-detail.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student-detail',
  templateUrl: './student-detail.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class StudentDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service:StudentDetailService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
  }

  resetForm(form?:NgForm)
  {
    if(form !=null){
      form.resetForm();
      this.service.formData = {
        Id :0,
        Name :'',
        StudentSubjects :null
      }
    }

  }

  onSubmit(form:NgForm)
  {
    this.service.postStudentDetail(form.value).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.resetForm(form);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err)
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And a Service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentDetail } from './student-detail.model';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentDetailService {
  formData :StudentDetail;
  readonly rootURL = 'http://localhost:31047/api';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postStudentDetail(formData:StudentDetail)
  {
    return this.http.post(this.rootURL+'/StudentDetail',formData)
  }
}
```

I understand that the "service" variable of the component is returning null, but when I printed in the  `ngOnInit()` function is not null. I've tried to use the `*ngIf="service"` command with no success, so I don´t know why this error is showing. Somebody knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `*ngIf="service.formData"`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan When I do that, the error disappears, but my form disappears as well.

Comment: why do you have service calls in your template? this is a crime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are trying to read the `Name` property of the `service.formData`, which is null.

   Instead of `*ngIf="service"` do, `*nfIf="service.formData"`
2. In the `resetForm` method you are initializing the `this.service.formData` only, if the argument is not null. In the `ngOnInit()` you are calling that method without parameters, so the formData will not be initialized. You need to initialize it first.

Comment: I tried this. And the error disappears but the text field disappears as well.

Comment: @YesidBejaranoCamacho I have updated, my answer. Please, check it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized your formData object on component init.

Initialize it before resetForm in ngOnInit and your error should be gone.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.service.formData = {
        Id :0,
        Name :'',
        StudentSubjects :null
      }
this.resetForm();
}
```